# I got error in ASP.net core MVC and Azure iot hub

Tags: c#, azure, asp.net-core, azure-iot-hub

I`m Novice 
Now I try to use  ASp.net core  to get some in Azure iot hub with this tutorial:https://ztirom.at/2016/03/frist-steps-azure-iot-hub/
but when I got a some error

[image]

What is something wrong happen?
how can I fix it or Another way to get some data from iot hub. 
thank you everyone

[this is my iothubconnectionstring part](https://i.stack.imgur.com/U37YN.png)

Comment: The link you provided is about .net framework. It is different from asp.net core, you could refer to this [article](https://github.com/niksacdev/samples.iot.simulator).

Comment: Hi Sunday, exception happens at regManager.GetDevicesAsync(), right? So you can create device(regManager.AddDeviceAsync) successfully?

Comment: @JoeyCai oh Thank you I will try that

Comment: @RitaHan-MSFT  thank you  but i tried but  it cant to  connect  with iot hub

Comment: @JoeyCai I cant open that Solution on  VS2013 , VS2015 and VS2017

Comment: @Sunday Can you show the format of the connection string(IOTHUBSTRING in the tutorial you linked) you used?

Comment: @RitaHan-MSFT yeah i did

Comment: @Sunday Does your connection string has this format: HostName=[HUB NAME].azure-devices.net;SharedAccessKeyName=iothubowner;SharedAccessKey=[KEY VALUE] ?

Comment: Are you using physical device to connect to the Azure IoT Hub? In my case I had a problem with time zone - it was different on my device and I got  unauthorized status even if my connection string was correct.

Comment: @Sunday Have you tried my solution? Please let me know if it helps.

Comment: @RitaHan-MSFT  thank you I ll try it

Comment: @RitaHan-MSFT  I tried but  I cant  detect  or check it  how can I get some data from iot hub ?

Comment: @Sunday You can use device object to access device data(`string deviceId = device.Id;`). Please check my update answer.

Answer (score 0):

I follow [this tutorial](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/tutorials/first-mvc-app/start-mvc?view=aspnetcore-2.1&tabs=aspnetcore2x) to create an ASP.NET Core MVC application. Install Microsoft.Azure.Devices(version 1.17.0) from NuGet. Call the regManager.GetDevicesAsync() in the controller and get the result successfully.

ManageDevices.cs in Controllers:

```
using System;
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc;
using Microsoft.Azure.Devices;
using Microsoft.Azure.Devices.Common.Exceptions;

// For more information on enabling MVC for empty projects, visit https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkID=397860

namespace WebApplication1.Controllers
{
    public class ManageDevices : Controller
    {
        public static string IOTHUBSTRING = "HostName=[IOT HUB NAME].azure-devices.net;SharedAccessKeyName=iothubowner;SharedAccessKey=[KEY]";


        // GET: /<controller>/
        public string Index()
        {
            return "This is my default action...";
        }

        public IActionResult GetDevices()
        {
            GetDevicesAsync();
            return View();
        }

        public async static Task<IEnumerable> GetDevicesAsync(int deviceCount = 8)
        {

            var regManager = RegistryManager.CreateFromConnectionString(IOTHUBSTRING);

            var devices = await regManager.GetDevicesAsync(deviceCount);

            foreach (var device in devices)
            {
                string deviceId = device.Id;
                DeviceStatus status = device.Status;
            }

            return devices;
        }
    }
}
```

You can use the following URI to execute the GetDevices method:

```
https://localhost:44387/ManageDevices/GetDevices
```

[image]

The result of the got devices:

[image]

You can have a try to see if it helps.

**Update:**

You can access the following device datas:

[image]

Comment: Thank you for your reply.   I tried to connect  but I could not to get devices  from iot hub. When i tried to connect internet  directly I can get devices from iot hub. So i think  the reason might be corporate network's proxy. Could you please consider again and let  me know  if  you know anything.

Comment: @Sunday It seems a [known issue](https://github.com/Azure/azure-iot-sdk-csharp/issues/477) and it has been fixed already for .net SDK. [Here](https://github.com/Azure/azure-iot-sdk-csharp/pull/569) is a sample of how to set the proxy explicitly in the application. Can you have a try and let me know if it helps.